# Rails, Ruby 1.9.3p0, and mysql gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm running CentOS6 and installed Ruby from source, along with Rails and some other staff.

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]  

rails -v
Rails 3.1.3
```

Some gems:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (3.1.3, 2.3.14)
actionpack (3.1.3, 2.3.14)
activemodel (3.1.3)
activerecord (3.1.3, 2.3.14)
activeresource (3.1.3, 2.3.14)
activesupport (3.1.3, 2.3.14)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (2.2.1)
bigdecimal (1.1.0)
bouncy-castle-java (1.5.0146.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
coderay (0.9.7)
columnize (0.3.5)
edavis10-object_daddy (0.4.3)
erubis (2.7.0)
fastercsv (1.5.0)
ffi (1.0.11)
hike (1.2.1)
hoe (2.12.4)
i18n (0.6.0, 0.4.2)
io-console (0.3)
jruby-openssl (0.7.4)
json (1.5.4)
linecache19 (0.5.13)
mail (2.3.0)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.17.2)
minitest (2.5.1)
mocha (0.10.0)
multi_json (1.0.4)
mysql (2.8.1)
mysql2 (0.3.11, 0.2.7)
net-ldap (0.2.2)
polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.3.5, 1.1.2)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.3, 2.3.14)
railties (3.1.3)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rdoc (3.9.4)
rmagick (2.13.1)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.26, 0.11.25)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby-mysql (2.9.4)
ruby-openid (2.1.4)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
rubygems-update (1.8.12)
rubytree (0.5.2)
shoulda (2.11.3, 2.10.3)
sprockets (2.0.3)
sqlite3 (1.3.5, 0.1.1)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.3, 1.2.5)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
tzinfo (0.3.31)
```

I need Rails in order to run `chiliproject`, but when running the following command

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

I get:

```
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Now with `--trace`:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace >> tmp/rake
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:7:in `block in require_library_or_gem'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/requires.rb:5:in `require_library_or_gem'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:61:in `mysql_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `block (2 levels) in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `block in checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
/var/www/html/chiliproject/vendor/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set.rb:218:in `quoted_left_column_name'
/var/www/html/chiliproject/vendor/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set.rb:94:in `acts_as_nested_set'
/var/www/html/chiliproject/app/models/issue.rb:33:in `'
/var/www/html/chiliproject/app/models/issue.rb:15:in `'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require_or_load'
/var/www/html/chiliproject/vendor/plugins/engines/lib/engines/rails_extensions/dependencies.rb:133:in `require_or_load_with_engine_additions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:451:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing_with_dependencies'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:375:in `const_get'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:375:in `block in constantize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:374:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/inflector.rb:374:in `constantize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:162:in `constantize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/observer.rb:157:in `observed_class'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/observer.rb:183:in `observed_classes'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/observer.rb:166:in `initialize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:141:in `new'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:141:in `block in instance'
:10:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/singleton.rb:139:in `instance'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/observer.rb:38:in `block in instantiate_observers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/observer.rb:36:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-2.3.14/lib/active_record/observer.rb:36:in `instantiate_observers'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:15:in `block in define_dispatcher_callbacks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `evaluate_method'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-2.3.14/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `run_prepare_callbacks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:631:in `prepare_dispatcher'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:185:in `process'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/var/www/html/chiliproject/config/environment.rb:39:in `'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4:in `block in '
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:158:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:176:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:157:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:66:in `block in run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/local/bin/rake:32:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Does anyone knows what's wrong with mysql gem files?

I also tried to install mysql gem files like this

```
gem install ruby-mysql2 --no-rdoc --no-ri -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/bin/mysql_config
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was just having similar problems and you may be doing what I was: I was using 'gem list' to determine what was installed (it lists `*** LOCAL GEMS ***` just like you show) and I saw `mysql`, but the `Gemfile` for my project was not requiring `bundler` to install `mysql`.

If you just type `bundle show` does it list 'mysql'?  If not, then the `Gemfile` in `chiliproject` is not causing `bundler` to install `mysql`.  I found this all very confusing until I realized I was confusing different ways of managing what gems are installed.

If you or others who comes this way are having the same issue, then perhaps this is helpful.  (And perhaps this poor explanation will encourage one of the rails gurus to elaborate for us.)

To say it another way, the list of your locally installed gems, isn't the same as the list installed in your app's **bundle** of gems (hence where the name of the `bundler` tool comes from). When you're running your app, and managing its dependencies with `bundler` you have to do everything within the `bundler` scope, in order to make sure it all works together. When you do that it's actually very straight forward and solves a lot of problems for you, but if you're coming from previous experience on apps that didn't use `bundler` then it just takes a little getting used to.

Comment: Thanks @normalocity - that is helpful.  Am I correct that this allows the *bundle* for production to get out of sync with the *bundle* for development?  (If so, that will help me isolate another problem.)

Comment: In practice, there shouldn't be a difference between the *development* and *production* bundle. Are you running into a situation where this is happening (that is, where `bundle show` doesn't show the same thing in both development and production)? Except for gems that are only needed for testing (e.g. `cucumber`, `rspec`, etc.), the the list should otherwise be the same.

Comment: My `bundle show` list is identical.  I guess I'll look onward for the problem; that isn't it.

Answer (score 4):

2 steps that worked for me:

1. Copy the file libmySQL.dll from /libhttp://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick   (in the folder /lib/) in c:/your/path/to/ruby/bin (Make sure your ruby bin is in your system PATH environnement variable)
2. The Default setup is given for MySQL with ruby1.8. If you're running Redmine with MySQL and ruby1.9, replace the adapter name with `mysql2` in your /config/database.yml file
   http://www.redmine.org/issues/10566

Answer (score 4):

Just on bundle install try this >>

`bundle install --without=test development sqlite postgres mysql rmagick`

This will install all required base dependencies, the mysql2 database adapter
Cause mysql adapter is not compatible with Ruby 1.9

And don't forget to change config/database.yml --> s/mysql/mysql2

\o/

Comment: I just had this problem on an old project (ruby 1.8) and `database.yml` was the problem! forgot to substitute `mysql` to `mysql2` in it.