# Migration Issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, migration

My application ruby version is ruby-1.9.3-p547 and rails version is "rails", "2.3.15"
and mysql is gem 'mysql2', '0.2.23'

when i tried to migration  I'm getting bellow errors

DEPRECATION WARNING: Rake tasks in vendor/plugins/annotate-models/tasks, vendor/plugins/deliver_later/tasks, and vendor/plugins/nulldb/tasks are deprecated. Use lib/tasks instead. (called from  at /home/ ....

!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails, Ruby 1.9.3p0, and mysql gem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453859/rails-ruby-1-9-3p0-and-mysql-gem)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in some deprecated mysql drivers, as stated above.

Have you tried updating the mysql gem?

Comment: Not really what you're after... You need to (1) remove the gem version from your Gemfile, (2) remove it from Gemfile.lock as well and (3) run `bundle install` afterwards. 

Please let me know how this goes.

Comment: Thank You for response Dimiter Shalvardjiev, the issue has been resolved now, unfortunately I specified in database.yml as adapter: mysql, so replaced it to mysql2.